# How do I use OnTriggerEnter() on a non-moving object?

Tags: unity-game-engine, triggers, 2d, collision-detection

I'm a new to game developing, and I'm making my first game in Unity, which is a top-down, 2D survival type game. In order to detect when the player hits a tree or other world object, I added invisible triggers on each side of the player, which I set active whenever you click. Whenever either the player or the target is moving, this system works perfectly, however, when the target is not moving, like a tree, the collision is not detected. I figure that the OnTriggerEnter function only works when a moving object collides with the trigger, however, I have no idea how to do it otherwise. Is there another function I can use, or some way I can fix this?

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        Debug.Log("hit");

        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Tree")
        {
            Debug.Log("hit tree");
            other.gameObject.GetComponent<TreeScript>().treeHealth--;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are your exact settings? I created a player object with a trigger and a rigidbody2D, and another one with a collider. They are on top of each other. Whenever I activate player/its trigger, the OnTriggerEnter2D is called. It also works if another object has trigger instead of collider.

Comment: Ah I added a Rigidbody to the colliders and now it works. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I ran into a problem after adding the Rigidbody. The triggers are child objects of the player, so when I add the Rigidbodies, the movement is not inherited, so the triggers detach from the player. Do you know a solution?

Answer (score -1):

You can try the:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{

}
```

If 2 objects collide with each other without using the "Trigger" option, the `OnCollisionEnter2D` will be called.

A quick example where to use the 2 different methods are as follow:

- Use the `OnTriggerEnter2D()` method in a racing game where you want to detect when a car goes through the finish line and you want to use a trigger because you don't actually care for the collision.
- Use the `OnCollisionEnter2D` method to detect when 2 cars collide with each other and you don't want the 2 object to go through each other.